# Perform .each function after first table row

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code

```
 $("#description tr").each(function(){
            var description;
            var chargecode;
            var amount=0;
```

.......the code continues but what I am interested in is to do the each function after the first row. My first table row has the titles so my code keeps getting null variable values and so on. Is this possible or should I just separate the title row as a different table? 
All help appreciated

Comment: Couldn't you add a `class` attribute to all rows apart from the first row and use `$("#description tr.class")` ?

Comment: As a matter of semantics, you should place your first `tr` within a `thead` and the others in `tbody` so that you can select `#description tbody tr`.

Comment: @zzzBov Yours is the solution I prefer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to the `each()` callback is the index. You could use that or you could define you table properly with `<thead>` and `<tbody>` and then use `$("#description tbody tr")`

Comment: While the other solutions should work, I think this is the most "correct" solution. If your first table row is a head, mark it as such and then you can select the table body using tags instead of classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("#description tr:not(:first-child)")
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KntKA/

Another option is `$("tr:nth-child(n+2)")`, but it doesn't read quite as nicely.

Comment: Did not work as expected. thanks though. I have multiple cells

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a class to the first row (or to all the others) and filter on that (look at the [not-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) or you can use the index of the loop (which is the first parameter) which increments on every iteration and than you simple skip the first one (or you add your own counter). Of course, a better solution is:

```
$("#description tr:not(:first-child)")
```

Which uses both the [not-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) as the [first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector.
You can also use the [greater than](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector:

```
$("#description tr:gt(0)")
```

So many options....I would go for the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
 $("#description tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
            var description;
            var chargecode;
            var amount=0;
```

The `tr:gt(0)` should only get rows with in index higher than zero, therefore ignoring the first row.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/rPMUh/

Comment: I would note that `:gt(0)` assumes there's only one table. If you have multiple tables, `:gt(0)` will skip over the first header, but not the rest.

Comment: That's a good point. Given that the selector first selects the table by id though, it seemed reasonable to assume they'd only be one table in this case.

Comment: I have multiple tables and for some reason it didn't work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#description tr:gt(0)").each`. The `:gt(0)` stands for "whose index is *greater then* 0" and it will filter the matched elements by their index in occurring on the page. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/).